How to pass property from child to parent
In my app.vue I have this promts component:
<Promtscomponent :promts='promts'></Promtscomponent>
<script>
    import Promtscomponentfrom '../components/Promtscomponent.vue';
    data() {return{
       promts:{'size':1,'promts':['simplepromt']}}

</script>

And in my Promtscomponent.vue I want to change promts property.
for example let's say I want to add another promt to it. So promts={size:2,promts:["simplepormt1","simplepormt2"] 
Then I need to pass this promts back to my app.vue where I can also do something with it (like pass to anther child component or send xhr to server)
I am a little bit stuck how do I do this?
I know I can use $emit to pass event from child but it feels so wrong
because:
I get promts from app.vue -> send them to child Promtscomponent.vue -> modify them in child component -> send modified version to app.vue and vue will automatically pass it again from app.vue to promtscomponent.vue because I define this as property <Promtscomponent :promts='promts'>
So what is correct way to do this?
Hope the question is clear.
What is the common and correct way
To pass object from parent to child, considering that This object will be modified in child component and passed back to parent.
So we can continue working with our object in parent component

"promt" should be "prompt" so that it would be easier to read?

@A.L what.......?

The question mentions "promt" (without p) and "prompt'. Is it the same thing?

Using emit is the recommended and correct way for this use case.

Check out the docs: Vue docs: Component Basics - Listening to Events

In which way it's supposed to be modified? Isn't "size" excessive, considering that you already have array length? If you're able to assign a new value instead of mutating existing object, it could be made v-model instead of custom event.

@A.L didn't find it, but just in case it's just a typo

"it's just a typo" This question would be easier to read without the typo, and would avoid the risk that the typo is the source of the problem.

v-model will update the parent value when the value in the child changes Vue SFC Playground:
parent:
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Comp from './Comp.vue'

const obj = ref({count: 0})
</script>

<template>
  {{obj}}
  <Comp v-model="obj"></Comp>
</template>

child:
<script setup>
  const model = defineModel()
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="model.count++">model.count++</button>
</template>


what is ref keyword here ? const obj = ref({count: 0})
what does it mean?

This is creating a reactive object for your example. vuejs.org
